# Column doesn't exist

Tags: django, postgresql

I am making a Django App and having the following issue when I am trying to add something to the table 'device' of my app from the admin interface:
 column device.plID_id does not exist

Here is class:

```
 class Device(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True,help_text='URL page created from name')
    model_name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    plID = models.ForeignKey('onep_web.Platform', unique = False)
    sdkID = models.ForeignKey('onep_web.SDKVersion',unique = False)
    IPID = models.ForeignKey('onep_web.IPAddress',unique = False)
```

and output of sqall command:

```
    BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "device" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "name" varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    "slug" varchar(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "model_name" varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    "plID_id" integer NOT NULL,
    "sdkID_id" integer NOT NULL,
    "IPID_id" integer NOT NULL
)
;
CREATE TABLE "platform" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "platform_name" varchar(20) NOT NULL
)
;
ALTER TABLE "device" ADD CONSTRAINT "plID_id_refs_id_364a8522" FOREIGN KEY ("plID_id") REFERENCES "platform" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
CREATE TABLE "sdk_ver" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "language" varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    "version" numeric(100, 100) NOT NULL
)
;
ALTER TABLE "device" ADD CONSTRAINT "sdkID_id_refs_id_bb71f431" FOREIGN KEY ("sdkID_id") REFERENCES "sdk_ver" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
CREATE TABLE "ip_addr" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "ip" inet NOT NULL
)
;
ALTER TABLE "device" ADD CONSTRAINT "IPID_id_refs_id_7c42b845" FOREIGN KEY ("IPID_id") REFERENCES "ip_addr" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
CREATE TABLE "files" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "file" varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    "isConfig" boolean NOT NULL
)
;
CREATE INDEX "device_slug_like" ON "device" ("slug" varchar_pattern_ops);
CREATE INDEX "device_plID_id" ON "device" ("plID_id");
CREATE INDEX "device_sdkID_id" ON "device" ("sdkID_id");
CREATE INDEX "device_IPID_id" ON "device" ("IPID_id");
```

When there were only two tables Device and Platform everything was OK. After I added a few more tables I have this issue

Answer (score 0):

Django's manage.py, does not use or handles migrations (currently) you need to use south to alter tables (when you alter models):
http://south.aeracode.org/

Install south, follow the detailed instructions and you will easily maintain your schema up to date.

Comment: Is it the only solution? I have seen what is it and decided to figure out some more solutions

Comment: South is widely adopted as a migration tool in django projects and in fact it will soon become a tool of the core management utilities of Django.
It's easy to use (unless performing complex migrations in production environment) and stable.